# Noise Reduction when recording changes volume

Tags: noise-reduction

The person running the mixer (what's the proper term?) had the level too low and changed it during the performance.  It appears that he took four seconds to ramp it up.

The noise profile is different on the two ends, as shown in the graph below.  The bulk of it reflects the volume change, but I have a constant noise source that doesn't vary.

[image: frequency analysis]

After I use an envelope on the track, the volume and parts of the noise will match.  But part of the noise will not match after the envelope is applied.

If I use one profile on the "before" part, and one on the "after" part, then I won't have covered those four seconds.

I'm thinking I'd like to first remove only the band of noise that does not change, across the whole track.  **Does anyone know how I would do that** using Adobe Audition CC 2014?

(as an aside, the rough noise shape is visible *by eye* in any selection, even though other sound is mixed in.  That allowed me to track his volume changes in the recording even though there was no intentional metadata. Interesting.)

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea - not sure this answers your specific question because I don't use Adobe Audition, but might solve the problem anyway - cut the track at the problem spot so that the four second fade is duplicated at the end of your first sample, and at the beginning of your second sample.  Apply the appropriate noise reductions to both halves and then crossfade the two across the four seconds where your mixer was also fading, adjusting the fadeup and fadedown curves as necessary.

Comment: I see, that would hide a sudden change, even if it was not accurate. ... thinking about it, I suppose the over and under corrections would cancel out for the noise that varies with the input level, ah, if the constant noise was completely removed from both samples, mixing the results will still be zero.  Nice idea!